# Spring - Loose coupling between different application modules?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

My current project has multiple modules (NOT Java 9 modules) and I'm looking for a good way to do loose coupling between Spring-based application modules.

From my understanding, I could @Import configuration classes (from other application modules). But it has some limitations:

1. Dependency on implementation classes of other modules
2. No clear API to be exposed for the consumer modules

The disadvantages would limit the ability to replace a module by an equivalent module which implements same API.

I'm thinking about using interfaces for module APIs and the @Configuration classes would implement the API interfaces. And the @Import will be replaced by dependency on exposed API objects. I have  prototype code here https://github.com/tha2015/springmodules/blob/master/src/main/java/dsl/Main.java

Is there a better way to do loose coupling between application modules?

Thanks.